# Use Fody.EmptyConstructor on a separate project?

Tags: fody

I have a solution with two projects `Business` and `Domain` I'm using `Fody.EmptyConstructor` to create parameterless constructors for my domain models on runtime. It works well when I add the `Fody.EmptyConstructor` package to the Domain project, but I'd rather not have that as a dependency there and instead have it in Business. Is there a way to do so?

```
-Sln 
--Domain 
--Business (has reference to Domain) 
---FodyWeavers.xml
```

`FodyWeavers.xml`:

```
<Weavers xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="FodyWeavers.xsd">
  <EmptyConstructor />
</Weavers>
```

Thanks in regard for any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fody needs to be installed in the project it modifies, along with its addins. It does not modify projects transitively, nor can it modify another project.

But it won't add a dependency if you add the `PrivateAssets="all"` attribute to the `PackageReference` items of Fody and EmptyConstructor.Fody.

Depending on how the weaver is configured, Fody will remove references to the weaver libraries. This is the case for EmptyConstructor.Fody.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Maybe a stupid question but where will Fody remove references to weaver libraries from?

Comment: @DLO Not sure I understand your question.. But it will remove the reference to the `EmptyConstructor` assembly from the assembly your project produces. Since v6.6.1 it will also remove it from the deps.json file.